# SPD 2013 Workflow Unauthorized using AppStep

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a SPD 2013 workflow attached to a list which runs when an item is added. The workflow attempts to update a field of the item. That action is wrapped in an AppStep.

Normal users of the list only have "Read" and "Add" privileges to the list, no edit. When the workflow is automatically initiated upon addition, it immediately enters the suspended state with a "401 Unauthorized" error.

From what I can determine, it seems that the custom permission on the list (read and add) is taking precedence over the power of the AppStep, preventing the field from being updated. Is this a correct assessment?

Moreover, is there a way to achieve this task under these constraints using an SPD workflow? I considered trying to make a REST call to the web api but I am fairly certain that will run in to the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling and then re-enabling **Workflows can use app permissions** site feature

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Same result.